# How can I analyze a Slow Query log for a WordPress install?

Tags: mysql, performance, wordpress

I have been experiencing some performance issues on a WordPress install. I have run multiple Slow Query tests, and while I do see some consistency between them, I still can't pinpoint the problem.  Here are a few of the queries that I have seen multiple times:

```
SET timestamp=1333980631;
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (1442,4054) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 2;
```

and

```
### 1 Query 
### Total time: 3.015405, Average time: 3.015405
### Taking 3.015405 seconds to complete
### Rows analyzed 60
SET timestamp=XXX;
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE XXX=XXX AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (XXX) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'XXX' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'XXX') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT XXX, XXX;

SET timestamp=1334004964;
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (125) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 8;
```

and

```
### 1 Query 
### Total time: 1.593301, Average time: 1.593301
### Taking 1.593301 seconds to complete
### Rows analyzed 19755
SET timestamp=XXX;
SELECT /*!XXX SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `wp_posts`;

SET timestamp=1333978522;
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `wp_posts`;
```

I notice that `wp_term_taxonomy` seems to come up, along with `wp_posts`, and some others.  My question is, how can I narrow down these results and find the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can:

1. use [plugin performance profiler](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/p3-profiler/) to benchmark and pinpoint problematics plugins
2. use [new relic](http://newrelic.com/) to find an issue
3. use [Debug Objects](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-objects/) to dump data for queries etc.

queries you showed looks like usual wp-admin queries, or pager query to define how many pages to show on listings.

you could also try simplest approach - to disable plugins one by one to determine which one is generating your problematic queries.